# IBOutlet nil - button

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, iboutlet

I have a HomeController and a registerController. The HomeController is embedded in a navigation controller and is the root view controller. If I present the registerController modally in HomeController's ViewWillAppear:

```
let reg = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signup") as! RegisterController
reg.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
reg.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal
reg.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(reg.view)
```

There is no problem. BUT if I present it by pushing it on the navigation controller stack:

```
let v = RegisterController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(v, animated: true)
```

the app crashes and says the IBOutlet for the signUp button (which is in registerController) is nil. I've re-created the outlet and cleaned the project and restarted xcode and nothing has worked...

Comment: Can you post your viewWillAppear code here?

Comment: @HPM the first snippet of code is my VWA. that's the only code in it

Comment: Matt answered your question check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s not a “bug”. Your code is what’s at fault. It has nothing to do with pushing vs presenting. It’s that this line is wrong:

```
let v = RegisterController()
```

That creates a barebones view controller with no outlets hooked up. The outlets are hooked up in the storyboard instance of this class. Create the view controller *from the storyboard* as you did in the first code, and all will be well.

```
let v = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signup") as! RegisterController
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'll give it a try. But I'm using this same code (let v = HTPController() )  in the same file for HTPController and it works as expected though. It also has a button. What is wrong about this specific one?

Comment: @user7804097 That button probably isn't connected either. `HTPController` doesn't crash because you have not used that button in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad`. Try pressing that button, it shouldn't do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @user7804097 It simply is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation everyone. That makes perfect sense! I can't accept for another 3 minutes